# WordPress: How do I add default item with value as empty string ('') using wp_dropdown_categories

Tags: wordpress

I am using `wp_dropdown_categories` in one of my custom forms. I want to add an additional item at top of the list with an `empty` string so that it renders like:

```
<select id="cmd" name="cmb" required>
   <option value=''>Select your language</option>
   <option value='2'>English</option>
   <option value='3'>Spanish</option>
   <option value='4'>Italian</option>
   <option value='5'>German</option>
</select>
```

This will allow me to use the native `required` attribute of `HTML5` and the validation will fire automatically. I tried `show_options_all` already but the value of for this option comes up `0`, which won't validate by **`required`** attribute.

```
<?php $args = array(
    'show_option_all'    => 'Select one',
    'show_option_none'   => '',
    'option_none_value'  => '-1',
    'orderby'            => 'Name',
    'order'              => 'ASC',
    'taxonomy'           => 'category',
    'hide_if_empty'      => false,
    'value_field'        => 'term_id',
); ?>

<?php wp_dropdown_categories( $args ); ?>
```

Is there a pure WordPress way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try using `show_option_none` and `option_none_value`. I am not sure what your current argument list is, but add these:

```
<?php $args = array(
    'show_option_none'   => 'Select your language',
    'option_none_value'  => '',
); ?>
```

Let me know if this solves your problem. This will create an option with the desired empty value (""), with your text (Select your language).
More info here: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_dropdown_categories

Comment: Perfect :) Thank you!